# How do i convert columns into rows for each status

Tags: sql

Data is saved in a table is as below.
[image]

I need to show data as below.
[image]

Please suggest a query

Comment: Why you changed from text to picture? just tag required _RDBMS_ ( mysql,sql-server,Oracle)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would do it in SQL Server:

```
  SELECT Name, 'Joined' AS [ACTION], JOIN_DT AS ACTION_DATE
  FROM SomeTable
UNION ALL
  SELECT Name, 'Started' START_DTTM
  FROM SomeTable
UNION ALL
  SELECT Name, 'ended', END_DT
  FROM SomeTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT Name, Action, Action_Date FROM (
       SELECT Name, 'Joined' as Action, JOIN_DT as ACTION_DATE FROM TableA
       UNION ALL
       SELECT Name, 'Started', START_DT FROM TableA
       UNION ALL
       SELECT Name, 'Ended', END_DT FROM TableA)
    ORDER BY Name;
```